# Redraw only one texture, not all of them

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm a little noob with XNA and I've encountered a problem. I have one texture called "dot", that I use to draw a line across the screen. Then I have a texture that I call "tool", that I want to move around when I touch it with my finger. The problem I have is that for the tool to be cleared and redrawn I call the graphicsDevice.Clear-method in XNA. But when I do that, my lines also disappears. So my question is how can i move around the tool, without causing my lines to disappear? Is there a way to only redraw the tool, without redrawing the lines? Heres a snippet of my code, first update-method:

```
protected override void Update (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState ();

        foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection) {
            if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed) || (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Moved)) {
                toolPos = touchCollection [0].Position;
            }
        }
        base.Update (gameTime);
    }
```

And the draw-method:

```
        protected override void Draw (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.Black);
        newVector = nextVector (oldVector);

        spriteBatch.Begin ();
        DrawEvenlySpacedSprites (dot, oldVector, newVector, 0.9f);
        spriteBatch.Draw (tool, toolPos, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End ();

        oldVector = new Vector2 (newVector.X, newVector.Y);
        base.Draw (gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `RenderTarget2D` with `RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents`. If you didn't use render targets yet, here's a tutorial: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/render-to-texture

All you have to do is to specify `RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents` in target's constructor, draw dots to it, and draw the target and tool to the screen. It should look like this:

```
protected override void Draw (GameTime gameTime)
{
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.Black);
    newVector = nextVector (oldVector);

    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
    spriteBatch.Begin ();
    DrawEvenlySpacedSprites (dot, oldVector, newVector, 0.9f);
    spriteBatch.End ();

    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget, new Vector2(), Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw (tool, toolPos, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End()

    oldVector = new Vector2 (newVector.X, newVector.Y);
    base.Draw (gameTime);
}
```

Comment: I created a render target and wrote my draw method as you did, but didn't quite understand where in the constructor I was going to put the Preservecontents, so I did this:
   renderTarget.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.RenderTargetUsage = RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents;

However the dots don't get preserved, so I'm guessing I'm doing something really wrong here. Do you know what I'm missing? Thanks so much for the help btw.

Comment: Render target has overloaded constructor, and tutorial doesn't show the right one for this task. Here's the overload you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433785.aspx